# Asp.Net 5(Core 1.0) Class Library System.Text.RegularExpression

Tags: asp.net, regex, namespace, expressões, asp.net-core

Como utilizar o namespace System.Text.RegularExpression no Asp.Net 5, estou com um projeto e fui atualizar ele para o asp.net 5, meu problema foi que não consigo utilizar Expressões regulares no mesmo e n consigo referenciar o namespace em questão.

Comment: Só um adendo: ASP.NET agora se chama ASP.NET Core 1.0

Comment: jbueno, vc sabe como resolver? isso eu já sabia, e que o asp.net core vai morrer tb já sabia, pois vai ser anexado ao .net core q está para sair, se puder ajudar a resolver agradeço...abç!

Comment: Não conheço muito sobre o .NET Core ainda, estou procurando algo pra te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei essa questão nas issues do beta ainda e foi resolvido adicionando a dependência "System.Text.RegularExpressions" no project.json.

Pelo que eu entendi, agora o Regex é uma biblioteca isolada do System.Text

**Fonte:**
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1454